# Tsung: CPU usage value from munin too high

Tags: erlang, load-testing, munin, tsung

I am struggling to get munin reporting working when running a Tsung load test.
My set up is as follows.

**Web site staging server (staging4):**

- 2 CPUs

**Tsung server**

- 2 CPUs

My Tsung server has an SSH tunnel to staging4 on port 4950 see my tsung.xml configuration below:

```
    <monitoring>
      <monitor host="localhost" type="munin">
        <munin port="4950" />
      </monitor>
   </monitoring>
```

When I start my load test I get the following error message every 10 seconds:

```
   =INFO REPORT==== 16-Nov-2011::16:04:09 ===
        ts_os_mon_munin:(4:<0.72.0>) CPU usage value from munin too high, skip (host "ip-10-48-177-212.housetrip.com" , cpu  8761644.1)
```

I maybe wrong but I think this is because our staging 4 server has 2 CPUs and so the resulting CPU % is greater than 100%.
I checked through the Tsung code and their didn't seem to be an option to set the number of CPUs referenced in the monitoring XML element https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung_controller/ts_config.erl

However there does seem to be a CPU setting on the munin plugin wrapper https://github.com/processone/tsung/blob/master/src/tsung_controller/ts_os_mon_munin.erl

Has anyone come across this before? Is there anyway I can get the munin values to be returned in my log file?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with munin, but I know that Tsung doesn't handle multicore CPUs very well.

To avoid Tsung crashes when running massive Tsung load from a client I used this workaround on a 4 core CPU.

```
<clients>
    <client host="myhostname" use_controller_vm="false" weight="1"/>
    <client host="myhostname" use_controller_vm="false" weight="1"/>
    <client host="myhostname" use_controller_vm="false" weight="1"/>
    <client host="myhostname" use_controller_vm="false" weight="1"/>
</clients>
```

As you can see, the trick is to set up one client Tsung erlang node per available core.
Maybe this trick can solve your munin problem also.